# Stop div moving off page when shrinking screen when using translate

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Aloha - I'm a css newbie and having trouble trying to get a div to stay where I want it to when shrinking. Here is my codepen and accompanying code. Please note I have bootstrap installed on the pen.

https://codepen.io/DarrenHaynes/pen/BpNvxb

HTML:

```
<div id="changing-background" class="spiritual-background">
  <div class="quote-box">
    <h2>When the going gets tough, the tough get going. Just like a 747 boeing. And some more text too. And another line for extra long quotes. And a little bit more for 5 lines
    </h2>
    <h3>- Billy Ocean</h3>
  </div>

  <div class="toolbar">
    <button type="button" id="spiritualQuote" class="btn btn-info"> Spiritual Quotes</button>
    <button type="button" id="techQuote" class="btn btn-info"> Tech Quotes</button>
    <button type="button" id="lifeQuote" class="btn btn-info"> Life Quotes</button>
    <button type="button" id="inspirationalQuote" class="btn btn-info"> Inspirational Quotes</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
html, body{
  height: 100%;
}
.spiritual-background { 
  height: 100%;
    background-image: url(https://s19.postimg.org/uuqru6leb/feng_sway_resized.jpg) ;
    background-position: center 25%;
    background-repeat:  no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size:  cover;
    background-color: #999; /* change this color */ 
}

.toolbar {

}

.quote-box {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 500px;
  margin-right: 5%;
  transform: translate(10%, -30%);
  padding: 0.1em 0.4em;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0); 
}

.toolbar {
  text-align: center;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 2em;
  padding-bottom: 0.5em;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 0.5em;
}
```

If you see my class .quote-box (I will be using jquery to put random quotes into the box, so the text size will keep changing), I want the text to not move out of the screen as I shrink the page width (and height for that matter). I want the quote box to stay on the right side of the page.

I did start to use media queries, but found that I need to make endless amounts of them given the dynamic nature of `transform translate`.

I also tried to use bootstrap row with columns for the quote box. Basically setting an empty column width of 7, followed by a width of column 4 for the quote box itself, and then an empty column width of 1 to create some space on the right of the quote box. I had a real hard time however trying to get that box where I wanted it using this method.

Any advice appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a made a simple solution for you!
See the snippet down below because I made your code slightly different.

Note: Run the code snippet and then click in the right of snippet "full page" button OR Copy and Paste this code and see if it fits you.

```css
.spiritual-background { 
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left: 0;
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
 background-image: url(https://s19.postimg.org/uuqru6leb/feng_sway_resized.jpg) ;
 background-position: center 25%;
 background-repeat:  no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
 background-size:  cover;
 background-color: #999; /* change this color */ 
}
.toolbar button {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.toolbar,.quote-box {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.quote-box h3{
    text-align: right;
}
.quote-box {
  margin-top: 80px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="changing-background" class="spiritual-background">
</div>
<div class="toolbar">
   <button type="button" id="spiritualQuote" class="btn btn-info"> Spiritual Quotes</button>
   <button type="button" id="techQuote" class="btn btn-info"> Tech Quotes</button>
   <button type="button" id="lifeQuote" class="btn btn-info"> Life Quotes</button>
   <button type="button" id="inspirationalQuote" class="btn btn-info"> Inspirational Quotes</button>
</div>
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-6">
         <div class="quote-box">
            <h2>When the going gets tough, the tough get going. Just like a 747 boeing. And some more text too. And another line for extra long quotes. And a little bit more for 5 lines
            </h2>
            <h3>- Billy Ocean</h3>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you that worked great! Made things responsive and the ability to fine tune the position of the quote box as needed. I added a few media queries and a js function to add and remove (exchange) the bootstrap columns to get things how I want them looking on mobile devices.

Comment: I'm glad that worked and awesome, you are going great. 

Keep up the good work.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
.quote-box {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 20px; /* set right, not left */
  width: 30%; /* width is percentage of parent */
  transform: translate(10%, -30%);
  padding: 0.1em 0.4em;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0); 
}
```